# mouseover image stuck in loop

Tags: javascript, if-statement, mouseover

I have been making this JavaScript code to display multiple images in one frame on mouse over.

But I get stuck in the setInterval loop and the images keep on changing although I exited the frame.

It is definitely stuck in the function `change()`.

I can not find a way to exit this as I move my cursor.

Could you give me a hand?

```
let start = 0;

const imageChange = document.querySelector(".image");

imageChange.addEventListener("mouseover", set_time);
imageChange.addEventListener("mouseout", end);

function set_time() {
  setInterval(change, 1500);
}

function change() {
  if (start < 3) {
    console.log(start);
    imageChange.src = "/img/image" + start + ".jpg";
    start++;
  } else {
    start = 0;
  }
}

function end() {
  start = 0;
  imageChange.src = "/img/image" + start + ".jpg";
}
```

Comment: This is javascript, not java. They are two totally different languages.

Comment: if `start==0`, the condition `start<3` is still true. You probably start an executor in the `setInterval`method but you don't stop it in the `end`method

Comment: yes it does!! thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) to stop the continuous execution of the function.

```
let intvl;
function set_time() {
  intvl = setInterval(change, 1500);
}
function change() {
  if (start < 3) {
    console.log(start);
    imageChange.src = "/img/image" + start + ".jpg";
    start++;
  } else {
    start = 0;
  }
}

function end() {
  start = 0;
  clearInterval(intvl);
  imageChange.src = "/img/image" + start + ".jpg";
}
```